# Event is required error when creating Call-To-Action Post on Google My Business

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-api-nodejs-client, google-my-business-api, google-my-business

I have the following code to create a new **Call-To-Action** post for a Google My Business Location as shown below:

```
const { google } = require('googleapis');

let locationURL = `https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/${accountId}/locations/${locationId}/localPosts`

let requestBody = {
    "languageCode": "en-US",
    "summary": "Test Call to action Post",
    "callToAction": {
        "actionType": "SIGN_UP",
        "url": "http://www.example.com",
    },
    "topicType": "OFFER"
}

let googleOAUTH2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(process.env.GOOGLE_APP_CLIENT_ID,
                           process.env.GOOGLE_APP_CLIENT_SECRET);
 googleOAUTH2Client.setCredentials(credentials); //Credentials code redacted
    
try {
    let locationRes = await googleOAUTH2Client.request({
        url: locationUrl,
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(requestBody)
    });
    let { data } = locationRes;
    console.log(`ResponseData=${data, null, 2}`);
} catch (e) {
    let err = e?.response?.data
    console.log(JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
}
```

But all I keep getting back is the error message below:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "badRequest"
            }
        ],
        "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
        "details": [
            {
                "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.mybusiness.v4.ValidationError",
                "errorDetails": [
                    {
                        "code": 2,
                        "field": "event",
                        "message": "event is required"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Which got me wondering. Why is event required for a Call to Action Post?. The [Docs](https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/posts-data#call_to_action_posts) never made any mention of that in the sample codes.

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an `event` (see [`event`](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations.localPosts#LocalPost.FIELDS.event)) for topic types `EVENT` and `OFFER`.

The [Docs](https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/posts-data#call_to_action_posts) that you reference appear incomplete.

Google [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer) is (always) your friend.

Search "my business" to get to [Business Profile APIs](https://developers.google.com/my-business/ref_overview).

Then [`localPost`](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations.localPosts) is the method that you're using to see definitive documentation.

The request body is type [`LocalPost`](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations.localPosts#LocalPost) and this describes [`event`](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations.localPosts#LocalPost.FIELDS.event) with the requirement mentioned above:

> Event information. Required for topic types EVENT and OFFER.

Google provides SDKs (called "libraries") for **all** its services in several languages including Node.js. For Business Profile APIs, you'll want to use [Node.js API Client Library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client)

Answer (score 0):

For those still searching for an answer to this type of error, here is how your payload parameter should be structured:

```
payload: JSON.stringify({
    "languageCode": "en-US",
    "summary": "Test Call to action Post",
    "callToAction": {
      "actionType": "SIGN_UP",
      "url": "http://www.example.com"
    },
    "event": {
      "title": "testing",
      "schedule": {
        "startDate": {
          "year": 2022,
          "month": 11,
          "day": 01
        },
        "startTime": {
          "hours": 05,
          "minutes": 00,
          "seconds": 00,
          "nanos": 00
        },
        "endDate": {
          "year": 2022,
          "month": 11,
          "day": 05
        },
        "endTime": {
          "hours": 10,
          "minutes": 00,
          "seconds": 00,
          "nanos": 00
        }
      }
    },
    "topicType": "OFFER"
  })
```